# Jquery modal is not working in another file

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angularjs, modal-dialog

I am working with website(frontend in angularjs and backend in nodejs),i have popup which is
apperaring after click on <kbd>signup/login</kbd> button (file path is `"/var/www/html/views/common/header.html"`)
now i want to appear same popup on <kbd>search</kbd> button (file path is `"/var/www/html/views/user/mainScreen/mainscreen.html"`)

Here is my working code in `header.html`

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-right">
  <li>
    <button type="button"
            class="btn btn-info btn-lg hoj-blue-light login-reg-btn bold"
            data-toggle="modal" ng-click="openModal()">
      Login / Signup
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I tried with following code in `mainscreen.html` but not working for me

```
<button class="btn btn-success search-btn text-center"
        data-toggle="modal" ng-click="openModal()">
   <span class="hidden-xs">Search</span>
```

How can i open same dialog box in another file ?

Comment: Where is the data-target of the modal?

Comment: Mixing AngularJS and jQuery like this is asking for problems. Consider using an AngularJS modal library such as [uib-modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!modal)